# Update same tables records without specifying columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

table A - 60 columns - 100 records

table B - 60 columns(same as table A) - 10 records

What I need is to insert/update all records from table.B into table.A
without specifying exact columns( I need all of them).
Tables match by id.So I need to update all columns or create the record.

I have a working queries but Im describing all table columns..

Comment: please provide what queries you currently have.

Comment: (Seems like a horrible db design.)

Comment: You need describe the table colum(s) its required for a UPDATE query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jarlh mentioned it is truly horrible design. wanted to go ahead with the same design still, here is my solution slight modification of @Rahul answer

```
BEGIN 

 SELECT  
        COLUMN_NAME INTO @pk_column  
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage 
                WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1_name' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY' 

;


SET @table1 = 'table_1';
SET @table2 = 'table_2';

SET @statement = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table1,' t1 SELECT * FROM ',@table2,' t2  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t1.',@pk_column ,' = t2.',@pk_column);

PREPARE stmt_ready FROM @statement;
EXECUTE stmt_ready;

END
```

Be aware working with PREPARED STATEMENTS is tricky and hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) like

```
INSERT INTO tableA a SELECT * FROM tableB b
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a.column1 = b.column1;
```

Comment: Ok but how to not specify a.column1 etc.. ?!

Comment: No there is no way ... you will have to specify. moreover as @jarlh commented .. first consider improving your table design